# How to add database to device?

Tags: android

I have sqlite database in my system i need to add this data base to the device(in the application location).How to do this ????

Answer (score 0):

You basically add code in your application that creates the database the first time it's used (Android will take care of the internals):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

If your database is not very big - just place your DB file into assets and then during first run your application should just copy SQLite DB file from assets directory to your application data storage. [See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)